# Dagger 2 @Singleton does not working in LibGDX (kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, libgdx, dagger-2

I'm trying to write a game on Android with dagger 2 features. I have a problem with @Singleton.

I have created the module:

```
@Module
class SharedModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getDeviceService(): DeviceService = DeviceService()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun getAssetsService(): AssetsService = AssetsService()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getGameService(): GameService = GameService()
}
```

and the component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [SharedModule::class])
interface SharedComponent {
    fun inject(app: MazeSlayers)
    fun inject(screen: SplashScreen)
}
```

but when I try to inject objects I got always a new instance of it, app class:

```
class MazeSlayers : Game() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var assetsService: AssetsService

    @Inject
    lateinit var gameService: GameService

    override fun create() {
        DaggerSharedComponent.create().inject(this)
        gameService.game = this
        assetsService.add(Asset.LOGO)
        this.setScreen(SplashScreen())
    }

    override fun render() {
        super.render()
    }
}
```

and `SplashScreen`

```
class SplashScreen : ScreenAdapter() {
    lateinit var batch: SpriteBatch
    var img: Texture? = null

    @Inject
    lateinit var deviceService: DeviceService

    @Inject
    lateinit var assetsService: AssetsService

    @Inject
    lateinit var gameService: GameService

    override fun show() {
        DaggerSharedComponent.create().inject(this)
        batch = gameService.batch
        img = assetsService.getTexture(Asset.LOGO)
    }
...
```

What I do wrong?

**[SOLUTION]**

One shared kotlin object resolved my issue

```
object DI {
    val shared: SharedComponent = DaggerSharedComponent.create()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating your component twice. Hence each component will independently create its objects. @Singleton's effect is that if you ask the same component for the same binding twice you get the same object.

The solution is to somehow create your component only once and let it create all the objects you need. I have no idea what's the way to achieve that in LibGDX.

Comment: I'm a little disappointment, I thought there will be more "magic";) I added the solution to the question